# Change DropDown values on select of input using Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

Below is my form. What i am trying to do is on select of Customer i want to change the dropdown values of resolutionTypes.

```
 <Formik
          initialValues={formData}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            const fData = JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
            setSubmitting(true);
            saveFilterFromData(JSON.parse(fData));
            setTimeout(() => {
              setSliderValue(value);
              fetchOppReportData();
              setSubmitting(false);
              handleFilterVisible(false);
            }, 1000);
          }}
        >
          {({ submitForm, isSubmitting }) => (
              <Form>
                {isSubmitting && (
                  <ColoredLinearProgress
                    colorPrimary={colors.amber[200]}
                    barColorPrimary={colors.amber[800]}
                  />
                )}
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <Field
                    component={TextField}
                    type="text"
                    name="selectedCustomer"
                    label="Select Customer"
                    select
                    variant="standard"
                    margin="normal"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                  >
                    {customerList.map(option => (
                      <MenuItem key={uuidv4()} value={option.label}>
                        {option.label}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Field>
                </FormControl>
                <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <Field
                    component={TextField}
                    type="text"
                    name="resolutionTypes"
                    label="Resolution Types"
                    select
                    variant="standard"
                    margin="normal"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                  >
                    {resolutionTypes.map(option => (
                      <MenuItem key={uuidv4()} value={option.value}>
                        {option.label}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Field>
               <CaptureFormValueContext />

                </FormControl>
    </Formik>
```

Below is my CaptureFormValueContext function where I am trying to set resolution type values but I am facing an error: ' Maximum update depth exceeded error -'
Can anyone please tell me where I went wrong

```
const CaptureFormValueContext = () => {
    // Grab values from context
    const { values, submitForm, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();
    useEffect(() => {
      if (values.selectedDateFilterType === CUSTOM) {
        setIsCustom(true);
      } else setIsCustom(false);
      const customerId = Lo.filter(customerList, {
        label: values.selectedCustomer,
      });
      const resolutionType = Lo.filter(customerResolutionData, {
        CustomerId: customerId[0].value,
      });
      const mapResolutionType = MapResolutionTypes(resolutionType);
      setFieldValue('resolutionTypes', mapResolutionType[0].value);
      setResolutionTypes(mapResolutionType);
    }, [values, submitForm, setFieldValue]);

    return null;
  };
```

Comment: I believe the problem is that you're updating the values and your useEffect hook also has values in its dependencies, so this will become an infinite loop. You can try destructuring the values that you actually need and use those in your useEffect.

Comment: @Bob mapResolutionType contains an filtered array i need all the values in that array to be present in that dropdown in that case what should i do? Is Destructuring possible in that case too?

Comment: I believe it might still work. If you have an online working example of the code I might be able to debug it for you, but for now I can't so I'm not 100% sure what the problem is. I would recommend finding out what the cause of the infinite loop is, and then find a way to solve the problem. From what I can see in your code, the problem might be the values object. So, what happens when u remove the values dependency from the useEffect array? Does this prevent the infinite loop? If you can make a Codesandbox of  your problem I might be able to help more.

Comment: Please find a codesanbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-breeze-h1kn9?file=/src/App.js